# grails/hibernate: add pessimistic locking on using creteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, pessimistic-locking

I tried to add a pessimistic locking in my creteria as it shown in the doc
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking but I had an exception:

"ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Feature not supported: "FOR UPDATE && JOIN"; SQL statement:
...
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query"

I tried to add the lock in two places:

```
def ParentInstance = Parent.createCriteria().get {
    Childs {
            idEq(ChildInstance.id)
            lock true
    }
```

And

```
def ParentInstance = Parent.createCriteria().get {
    Childs {
            idEq(ChildInstance.id)      
    }
    lock true               
}
```

Additional question: Is it the right way to use the pessimistic locking the an association?

Thank you

**Domain**

```
class Parent{   
     static hasMany = [Childs:Child]    
}

class Child{

}
```

**Datasource.groovy**

```
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
            username = "sa"
            password = ""
        }
        hibernate {
            cache.use_second_level_cache = true
            cache.use_query_cache = false
            cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
        }
        // environment specific settings
        environments {
            development {
                dataSource {
                    dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
                    url = "jdbc:h2:myApp_prodDb;MVCC=TRUE"
                }
            }
            test {
                dataSource {
                    dbCreate = "update"
                    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:myApp_testDb;MVCC=TRUE"
                }
            }
            production {
                dataSource {
                    dbCreate = "update"
                    url = "jdbc:h2:myApp_prodDb;MVCC=TRUE"
                    pooled = true
                    properties {
                       maxActive = -1
                       minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
                       timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
                       numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
                       testOnBorrow=true
                       testWhileIdle=true
                       testOnReturn=true
                       validationQuery="SELECT 1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using hibernate database

Comment: Hibernate is just a layer between your app and an underlying database. That database can be H2 (in-mem database provided by Grails), PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, MySql... Can you list the contents of your `DataSource.groovy` file (be sure to delete any private information such as IPs and passwords, however)?

Comment: Thank you, you are using the H2 database, but I think I see what the problem is now. Will post a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you form your query, Hibernate will execute different queries. The way your query is written Hibernate will perform a join - this can be good for performance because it means your joined entities will already be pre-fetched in the 1 query. For locking however this is bad as every joined table would have to be locked and this can have quite an effect on deep hierarchies. Thus your database does not allow it (I'm not even sure if any other does).

You will have to perform your query without joins. Depending on your domain class implementation a simple `Child.parent.id` could be done without touching the database and then your query becomes a simple `Parent.lock(Child.parent.id)`. It's hard to say without seeing the actual domain classes.

What you can always do is get the `Parent` in a non-locking query and then call the `lock()` method on the returned instance. I would suggest you take a look at this excellent [article](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2012/11/12/the-false-optimism-of-gorm-and-hibernate/) on locking things in GORM for more information.

Comment: I didn't use the statis method `belongsTo`, so cannot get the parent directly from the child right?

Comment: I added the domain classes

Comment: You could add `static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]` to your `Child` class and get access to the parent via either `child.parent` (which you would then `lock()`) or `Parent.lock(child.parent.id)` (see the difference between the two in the article I linked, but the later form is probably better).

You should be aware though that this will change the schema GORM generates - with your current setup, it creates a mapping table (probably called `parent_child`) and with the modified setup it would simply include a `parent_id` column in the `child` table instead.

Comment: When you perform a lock on the returned instance for a parent class, the childs are also locked or not?

Comment: No, the child objects are not locked. But if you always lock the parent first then the children may be safe as long as they have only 1 parent and other apps are not interacting with the database.. but please don't trust me 100% on this, try testing it first.